# Access nested tags from outer tag in JSP taglib

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, taglib

I'm creating own taglib and it's gonna have structure like this:

```
<taglib:Table data="someDataObject">
    <taglib:Column columnName="1" columnValue="111"/>
    <taglib:Column columnName="2" columnValue="222"/>
    <taglib:Column columnName="3" columnValue="333"/>
</taglib:Table>
```

So I want to render the table in Table tag. But for rendering process I have to know about table columns, which are described in children tags (Column).

I had an idea to create a collection in Table class and then access it from Columns (and add fields to this collection), but unfortunately outer tag is being rendering before creating nested tags (as I discovered using logging), so I don't have necessary information yet...